How to make Jest read jest.config file (not spec files) as ESM?
I can run my ESM .spec files with Jest. My question is about loading jest.config.ts file itself (rather than .spec.ts files) as ESM instead of CommonJS.
The file jest.config.ts imports an ESM module such as such as strip-json-comments (versions > 4.0 only support ESM).
jest.config.ts:
import strip from 'strip-json-comments' 

export default function config(){
  // call the esm function
  strip(...);
}

This causes the following error:
Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file jest.config.ts
  Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module node_modules/.pnpm/strip-json-comments@5.0.1/node_modules/strip-json-comments/index.js from jest.config.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in jest.config.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Please note that the ESM spec files can run normally, i.e. not importing any ESM module inside jest.config.ts not causing this error.
I added "type": "module" in package.json and run Jest like that:
node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --experimental-import-meta-resolve --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js

minimal reproduction

This should be specific to tsconfig, which isn't shown. You may need to provide a specific config for tests, see https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/14740

I added a minimal reproduction link @EstusFlask

Looks like a quirk of ts-node, which has a bunch of problems. Changing the name to jest.config.mts will likely fix this

jest doesn't support .mts files, it may be changed to .mjs, but I'll need to change all types annotations @EstusFlask

Config file is not handled by jest itself so it's a separate case. I checked it in this setup and it works.
